# Can you use null byte injection to exploit SQLi in Postgres?

Tags: sql-injection, null-byte-injection, postgresql

While testing, I do get an error when passing the input `asdf%00` to my applications username. The database in the backend spits an error, because Postgre [can't handle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE) `0x00` in text fields.

```
 <h4>PersistencyException</h4>
    <pre><code><strong>org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: ungültige Byte-Sequenz für Kodierung „UTF8“: 0x00</strong></code></pre>
```

Is this exploitable with an SQL injection, or do I assume correctly that it isn't?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to determine if there is an SQL injection or not